# Datetime input in SQL Server with Node.js out of range

Tags: sql-server, node.js, database

I have to run a query on SQL Server 2014 using the node.js `mssql` package. To do so, use the query below with the two input parameters. When I execute the T-SQL code, the following error shows up:

> RequestError: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

How can I solve it?

Input values:

- `IdCantiere`: 14
- `Data`: 2018-06-21 09:20:04.000

Node.js code:

```
async function CaricaRisorseCantiere(IdCantiere, Data) {

    var value = [];
    var query = "select  RisorseUmane.IdRisorseUmane,IdUtenteInserimento,u1.Nome+' '+u1.Cognome as InseritoDA,ExtraPreventivo,u2.Nome+' '+u2.Cognome as Risorsa,RisorseUmane.IdUtente,IdCantiere,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Data, 105) as Data,Descrizione,convert(varchar(5), OreInizio, 108) as OreInizio,convert(varchar(5), OreFine, 108) as OreFine,REPLACE(Pausa, '.', ':') as Pausa,convert(varchar(5), Cast(convert(varchar(5), (OreFine - OreInizio), 108) as datetime) - CAST(REPLACE(Pausa, '.', ':') as datetime), 108)  as TotaleOre   from RisorseUmane  inner join Utente as u1  on u1.IdUtente = RisorseUmane.IdUtenteInserimento   inner  join Utente as u2 on u2.IdUtente = RisorseUmane.IdUtente ";
    if (Data == "") {
        query = query + " where RisorseUmane.IdCantiere= @IdCantiere  order by convert(datetime, Data, 103) desc ";
    } else {
        query = query + " inner join RisorsaRapportoMobile on RisorsaRapportoMobile.IdRisorseUmane=RisorseUmane.IdRisorseUmane where RisorseUmane.IdCantiere= @IdCantiere and RisorsaRapportoMobile.IdRapportoMobile is null  and RisorseUmane.Data=convert(varchar,convert(datetime,@Data),105)  ";
    }
    const ret = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        new sql.ConnectionPool(DbConfig.config).connect().then(pool => {
            if (Data == "") {
                return pool.request().input('IdCantiere', sql.Int, IdCantiere).query(query)
            } else {
                return pool.request().input('IdCantiere', sql.Int, IdCantiere).input('Data', sql.VarChar, Data).query(query)
            }
        }).then(result => {

            resolve(result);
            sql.close();

        }).catch(err => {

            console.log("Errore Risorse Model: ", err)
            reject(err);
            sql.close();
        })
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < ret.recordset.length; i++) {        
        value.push({            
            IdRisorseUmane: ret.recordset[i].IdRisorseUmane,
            IdUtenteInserimento: ret.recordset[i].IdUtenteInserimento,
            InseritoDA: ret.recordset[i].InseritoDA,
            ExtraPreventivo: ret.recordset[i].ExtraPreventivo,
            Risorsa: ret.recordset[i].Risorsa,
            Data: ret.recordset[i].Data,
            Descrizione: ret.recordset[i].Descrizione,
            TotaleOre: ret.recordset[i].TotaleOre    
        })
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the input call:

```
request.input('Data', sql.VarChar, Data)
```

The call should be changed to:

```
request.input('Data', sql.DateTime, new Date(Data));
```

Also, the SQL clause:

```
and RisorseUmane.Data=convert(varchar,convert(datetime,@Data),105)
```

Should become

```
and RisorseUmane.Data=convert(varchar,@Data,105)
```

Comment: I had already tried your solution but it always gives me the same error I mentioned above

Comment: Thanks @riki, I'll test again!

Comment: your conversion generates me this 2018-06-21T07: 20: 04.000Z

Comment: Could you try changing the SQL: convert(varchar,convert(datetime,@Data),105) to simply convert(varchar,@Data,105)?  Thanks!